# Srvany Starts but Application doesn't

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-server-2008, software-as-a-service, saas

I used Instsrv and Srvany as to create a service on W2008; the Srvany service starts okay but the application does not start.

The application is TeamSpeak 3 btw.

I don't think it's an issue with my W2008 setup as I have a previous version of the application set up the exact same way and running perfectly. Also, I have no problem manually starting the application even when I copy and paste into the 'Run' box the path used for the application by Srvany.

I looked at Events but nothing there except notification that the service has entered the running state, didn't really expect any errors as the service has started even though the application hasn't.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[1] Is the process starting and then closing again immediately?  Watch what happens in the process list in Task Manager.

[2] I often find that toggling the "Allow service to interact with the desktop" setting for the service helps with this kind of problem.

[3] It could be a path problem: unfortunately, just because a command line works in the Run dialog doesn't necessarily mean it will work in all other contexts.  Try replacing the long path (especially any parts with spaces, like Program Files) with its short-name equivalent (e.g. PROGRA~1).  **dir /x** is helpful for finding short names.

Comment: I think it's probably something to do with the working path directory. Anyway, I've found a better solution than Servany, a little freeware programme called RunAsSvc available from http://www.pirmasoft.de/runassvc.php - it's much easier to use than messing about with Regedit and it my service is running fine with it.